# Team City 7.1 Configuration Parameters across Build Configurations

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I would like to define a variable on a TC configuration and would like to get its value on a different TC configuration that has a trigger dependency on the first one.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both configurations are in the same project, you can define a build configuration template that contains the shared parameter (i.e. variable).  Both active configurations must then reference that template -- use the 'Associate with Template' action to accomplish this.  The value of the shared parameter must be set in the template in order for the same value to be known to both configurations.

If you're trying to share build numbers (or other system-level parameters) between the configurations, there is [a special method](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/How+To...#HowTo...-Havethesamebuildnumberforsamesnapshotbuildsofdifferentbuildconfigurations) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use something like this to actually dynamically change the configuration parameters.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://build/guestAuth/action.html?add2Queue=bt876&name=env&value=test&name=env.number&value=%target.env.number%" -Method "Get" -Verbose
```

Comment: I noticed that you unaccepted my answer -- can you tell me what didn't work for you?